# Why I click on right side nav it doesn't show up item of ul li i wan't make it responsive

Tags: html, css

How to fix it it doesn't work on small screen it show right sidenav icon but I click it it doesn't show up. I want it to be show example Home, Menu, and submenu in small screen but why it can't be.

This is **html** file:

```
<div class="row preview-html" ng-show="screen == &#39;preview&#39;" ng-hide="loading">
        <div class="col-md-12"><div id="cssmenu"><div id="menu-button">Menu</div>
  <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</span></a></li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Menus</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="https://app.cssmenumaker.com/#"><span>Menu 1</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 1.1</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 1.2</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Settings</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
</div>
```

This is **css**:

```
    #cssmenu {
      background: #2a8a8f;
      margin: 0;
      width: auto;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 1;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu ul:after,
    #cssmenu:after {
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      height: 0;
      clear: both;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
      -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
      -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
      -o-transition: color .2s ease;
      transition: color .2s ease;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul {
      position: absolute;
      left: -9999px;
      top: auto;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li {
      max-height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
      -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
      transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
      background: #fff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #000;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 13px;
      right: 15px;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
      right: auto;
      left: 15px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      border: 3px solid transparent;
      border-left-color: #fff;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 15px;
      right: 15px;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
      right: auto;
      left: 15px;
      border-left-color: transparent;
      border-right-color: #fff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: none;
      color: #000;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 170px;
      padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
      color: #4cb6ea;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
    #cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
      background: #4cb6ea;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
      max-height: 72px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
      float: left;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
      text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right > ul {
      float: right;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
      right: 100%;
      left: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
      text-align: right;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 0;
      background: #fff;
      -webkit-transition: height .2s;
      -moz-transition: height .2s;
      -ms-transition: height .2s;
      -o-transition: height .2s;
      transition: height .2s;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
      padding-right: 40px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      background: #fff;
      height: 12px;
      width: 12px;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 13px;
      right: 14px;
      top: 16px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      border: 4px solid transparent;
      border-top-color: #2a8a8f;
      z-index: 2;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 16px;
      top: 21px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      font-weight: 700;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
      color: #000;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
      background: #000;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
      border-top-color: #fff;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
      left: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
      max-height: 72px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button {
      display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
      width: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
      width: 170px;
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
      width: 170px;
      display: block;
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
      #cssmenu > ul {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
      }
      #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right ul li a {
        text-align: left;
      }
      #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
        text-align: left;
      }
      #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
        text-align: left;
      }
      #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu > ul.open {
        max-height: 1000px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25);
      }
      #cssmenu ul {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu ul > li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
      }
      #cssmenu ul > li:after {
        display: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,
      #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,
      #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
      #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
        display: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li ul,
      #cssmenu ul li ul li ul,
      #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul,
      #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul,
      #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li ul,
      #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li:hover > ul {
        left: 0;
        position: relative;
        right: auto;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li ul li,
      #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
        max-height: 999px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
        padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px;
        color: #fff;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
        padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
        color: #000;
      }
      #cssmenu #menu-button {
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 22px;
        border-top: 2px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
        right: 20px;
        top: 16px;
        box-sizing: content-box;
      }
      #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
        display: block;`enter code here`
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 22px;
        border-top: 2px solid #fff;
        right: 20px;
        top: 26px;
        box-sizing: content-box;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong .

1st for ul after #menu-button the overflow is hidden so it wont show the ul container even if its there.

2nd color of each link inside menu is same as background . so change it to see the contents .or change the background to black or other color since font is white .

3rd you are using :after psudo element to show the hamburger icon so use the following to add click event to :after element.

```
<script>
 $('#cssmenu #menu-button').after().click(function(){
  $('#cssmenu').toggleClass('active');
 });
</scr
```

css to add inside @media query.

```
#cssmenu.active ul li a{
 color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu.active #menu-button + ul{
 overflow: visible;
}
#cssmenu.active #menu-button:after{
 pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: If my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.